# $(document).ready not work in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using following code in other browser(mozilla, chrome etc.) then working fine but if i use that same code in IE 7 then it's not working(work in IE 8+). no error given to me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? and have you closed your ready function?

Comment: He did, look behind the alert()

Comment: i am using `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>`  and i also closed ready function.

Comment: Current jQuery version: v1.7.2 - Upgrade to the newest and try it again.

Comment: That is a old version of jquery, is it possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: Do you have any Javascript code blocks before the jQuery call? Hit **F12** and see if you're getting any errors.

Comment: sorry, i tried `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>` but it also not working in IE7.

Comment: @kayen yes i use many javascript function before Jquery block. i also try using F12 but it also not work.

Comment: try `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: can you post the entire code? i doubt this has to do with just `ready()`

Comment: ok thanks to all. i got solution.  i use  `$(this).animate({   
   opacity: 0.8,   
    }, 500, function() {
   // Animation complete.
    });` in my javascript code so $(document).ready not working.  i remove that from my code now it works nicely. again thanks

Comment: @ketan you should accept kayen's answer. It's basically exactly what you figured out yourself.

Comment: i got solution but any one can give me answer that why i can't use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that there might be an error above the jQuery code block which might be stopping the execution on IE7.

Do this - load the page on IE7. On the bottom-left corner of the browser, if there's a yellow symbol double click on it and see what line is causing the execution to fail.